# Get child objects by id or parent object in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Let's say I have a `Broker` class which has a collection of `Accounts`. The `Broker` class maps to a database table called `brokers`, the `Account` class maps to a database table called `accounts`. i.e.

```
public class Broker
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<Account> Accounts
    {
        get { return _accounts; }
        protected set { _accounts = new HashSet<Account>(value); }
    }
    // other properties
}

public class Account 
{                
    public virtual Broker Broker { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
```

I want to write a method to return a list of accounts for a `Broker` and I'm not sure what the signature should be. I thought of two but not sure which to go for:

`IList<Account> GetBrokerAccounts(Broker broker)`

or

`IList<Account> GetBrokerAccounts(int brokerId)`

I'd be interested from a design point of view the pros and cons of each and what would be "best practise".

**Edit**

Here is my mapping file for my collection problem:

```
  <class name="MooDB.Domain.Broker,MooDB" table="brokers" >
    <id name="Id" column="brokerId" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <version name="Version" column="version" type="integer" unsaved-value="0" />
    <property name="Name" column="`name`" type="String" length="50" not-null="true" />
    <property name="IsActive" column="isActive" type="bool" not-null="true" />
    <property name="IsDefault" column="isDefault" type="bool" not-null="true" />
    <set name="BrokerInstruments" table="brokerInstruments" generic="true" inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="delete">
      <key column="brokerId" />
      <one-to-many class="MooDB.Domain.BrokerInstrument" />
    </set>
    <set name="Accounts" table="accounts" generic="true" inverse="true" lazy="false" cascade="delete">
      <key column="accountId" />
      <one-to-many class="MooDB.Domain.Account,MooDB"/>
    </set>
  </class>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would need any of the two methods when you can already access a list of accounts directly from the `Broker` object.

```
var brokersAccounts = broker.Accounts;
```

NHibernate would already do the required work for you.  In other words first find the broker object/entity and enumerate through its accounts.

Comment: In my database I have two accounts with brokerId = 1. If I load a Broker with brokerID = 1 and then examine the Accounts collection, there's only one account there (accountId = 1). Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a possible issue with your NHibernate mapping.  Make sure you have mapped your `Account` as a `bag` or `set` inside your `Broker`.

Comment: Yes my `Accounts` are mapped as a set. See my edit. Anything else you can think of?

Comment: Difficult to tell here.  When using `set`. Make sure to use ISet instead of IEnumerable.  You will have to use the `Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet`.  Also make sure to provide an implementation for `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for items that are added to a ISet.

Comment: <key column="accountId" /> should reference brokerId.

Answer (score 0):

Use the id, brokerId. It's a better practice (I don't believe in best practices) to use the simplest possible arguments and return types. Passing the id only also is typically much more useful in a stateless application, such as a web app.

Answer (score 0):

Use The Load method. It creates proxy and thus you avoid loading of the Broker if you are only interested in the accounts.

```
public IList<Account> GetBrokerAccounts(int brokerId)
{
    return session.QueryOver<Account>()
    .Where(x => x.Broker == session.Load(brokerId)).List();
}
```

So if you get the brokerId from UI there is no need to load the Broker object from the database since you know it exists in the database. The code above will basically create select * from account where broker = brokerId type of query. If you would use Get it would generate two queries. One for loading the Broker and second to get the accounts.